# How to render block layout from controller in magento 2?

Tags: layout, magento-2.0, controllers

I am tring to call block from the controller action but its not working and throwing me an error as

> Exception #0 (OutOfBoundsException): No element found with ID 'left'.

```
$this->_addContent($this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('\Demo\Test\Block\Adminhtml\Method\Edit'));

$this->_addLeft($this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('\Demo\Test\Block\Adminhtml\Method\Edit\Tabs'));
```

Can you please tell me how can i achieve above things?

Comment: From which controller, Its backend controller?

Comment: Yes, Its a backend controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not add blocks from the controller. Use the layout file for that.
But if you do, you need to call `$this->_view->loadLayout()` prior to adding your blocks.
and make sure your layout file has the main tag looking like this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

`layout="admin-2columns-left"` ensures you that the left column exists.